# Difficulty understanding the proof of sorting algorithm's lower bound

Tags: algorithms, trees, sorting

I'm reading the "Introduction to Algorithm", and in chapter 8.1, which is proofing the lower bound of comparison-based sorting algorithm, it says:

> Consider a decision tree of height $h$ with $l$ reachable leaves
>   corresponding to a comparison sort on $n$ elements. Because each of
>   the $n!$ permutations of the input appears as some leaf, we have
>   $n!\leq l$.

And my question is that Why the number of permutations ($n!$) is less than or equal to the number of reachable leaves ($l$)?

P.S. I'm learning algorithm out of interest, and don't have much knowledge about trees

Comment: Presumably this is a decision tree whose leaves are permutations of some collection of $n$ elements, and it is a "complete" decision tree in the sense that each of the $n!$ permutations are represented in some leaf. This is a natural condition for starting up an algorithm: without such "completeness", you have already removed some possible permutations, which means that either your algorithm will sometimes be wrong, or that you have "already done" some sorting before the algorithm has even started. Overall, up to this point everything is really just setup, not actually doing anything.

Comment: @lan Then what about "reachable leaves"? Are there any leaves that is not reachable? I thought $n!$ equals $l$ at first.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about "reachable" too much; if your graph is a rooted tree (as usual in these kinds of things) then all its leaves are reachable from the root. In principle though, $l$ could be greater than $n!$, if your decision sequences do not pair up exactly with the permutations.

Comment: @lan Is it because the reachable leaves may contains duplicate or similar leaves?

Comment: In principle yes. It just depends on how the algorithm works, as well as how the mapping from the algorithm to a decision tree is constructed.

Comment: @lan Thank you! Now I'm starting to understand!